# Replacing CoffeeScript files for each view in Rails 4.0.0, and linking them to the view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

When I create my scaffold, I have a `sessions.js.coffee` file automatically created in my `app/assets/javascripts` directory.

Since I want to use plain old JavaScript, I changed the name to `sessions.js` and wrote my javascript in there. How do I make sure that my `sessions.js` file is executed only for my sessions view? It seems like this was somehow linked automatically when using CoffeeScript, but goes away for the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `<%= javascript_include_tag "sessions" %>` at the top of the sessions view page.